SQLAlchemy Join statement introducing duplicates
I have two tables component and component_transform
class Component(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "component"

    component_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    component_serial_number: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(250), unique=True)
    component_transform: Mapped[List["ComponentTransform"]] = relationship(
    "ComponentTransform", back_populates="component"
)

class ComponentTransform(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "component_transform"

    transform_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    component_id: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey("component.component_id")
    )
    component_serial_number: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(250))
    component: Mapped["Component"] = relationship(
    "Component", back_populates="component_transform"
)

component has a one to many relation to component_transform. I have a function that needs to search for the serial_number. Now I want to be able to search the serial_number in either component or component_transform. Regardless of the matches I just want to return the one record being held in the component table.
I have the function below but it keeps returning multiple records. For example if have the serial_number "A" in my component table and "B", "C", "D" in the component_transform table. If I search for any of these I should only get the record back for A. Ofcourse they all share the component_id.
async def search_components(
    session: AsyncSession,
    component_serial_number: Optional[str] = None,
    component_name: Optional[str] = None,
    component_status: Optional[list[str]] = None,
    limit: int = 20,
    offset: int = 0,
) -> Sequence[ComponentSearchModel]:
    async with session:
        subquery_service_hrs = (
            select(
                DBMotorComponent.component_id,
                func.sum(DBMotorComponent.drilling_hrs).label("service_hrs"),
                func.sum(DBMotorComponent.drilling_hrs).label("life_hrs"),
            ).group_by(DBMotorComponent.component_id)
        ).subquery()

        statement = (
            select(DBComponent)
            .options(joinedload(DBComponent.part))
            .outerjoin(
                subquery_service_hrs,
                DBComponent.component_id == subquery_service_hrs.c.component_id,
            )
            .outerjoin(
                DBComponentTransform,
                DBComponent.component_id == DBComponentTransform.component_id,
            )
            .add_columns(
                subquery_service_hrs.c.service_hrs, subquery_service_hrs.c.life_hrs
            )
        )

        if component_serial_number is not None:
            statement = statement.where(
                or_(
                    DBComponent.component_serial_number.ilike(
                        f"%{component_serial_number}%"
                    ),
                    DBComponentTransform.component_serial_number.ilike(
                        f"%{component_serial_number}%"
                    ),
                )
            )

        if component_name is not None:
            statement = statement.where(
                DBComponent.component_name.ilike(f"%{component_name}%")
            )

        if component_status is not None:
            statement = statement.where(
                DBComponent.component_status.in_(component_status)
            )

        statement = statement.limit(limit).offset(offset)
        result = await session.execute(statement)
        components = result.fetchall()

        component_model = [
            ComponentSearchModel.model_validate(
                {
                    **component.__dict__,
                    "service_hrs": service_hrs or 0,
                    "life_hrs": life_hrs or 0,
                }
            )
            for component, service_hrs, life_hrs in components
        ]

    return component_model

I have tried doing a distinct but I am getting an error of ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
I have also tried to do a group_by on the DBComponent but getting a "Not a group by expression" error.

Use .distinct() to remove duplicates.

@Barmar Like I said in my post .distinct() is not working, its giving me an error.

I think the outerjoin to ComponentTransform is causing the duplicates.  You can just conditionally include a subquery in the WHERE clause if you are given the component_serial_number.  Then you can remove that second OUTER JOIN to ComponentTransform.
Something like this:
        if component_serial_number is not None:
            transform_subq = select(
                DBComponentTransform.component_id
            ).where(
                DBComponentTransform.component_serial_number.ilike(
                    f"%{component_serial_number}%"
            ))
            # Either component itself has sn or any of its transforms do
            statement = statement.where(
                or_(
                    DBComponent.component_serial_number.ilike(
                        f"%{component_serial_number}%"
                    ),
DBComponent.component_id.in_(transform_subq),
                )
            )


This worked great. To anyone in who may come across this issue later, the reason I could not use the distinct method was due to one of the columns in my tables being a CLOB. Unfortunately my DB does not allow the use of distinct in this case.
I also tried to use group_by but did not work for me without me hardcoding and listing out all the columns as part of the group_by.
